# How to configure Spring MVC to load context through ContextSingletonBeanFactoryLocator

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

There is a web application based on `Spring 3.2`. Here is how it's configured in web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MY-REST-API</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MY-REST-API</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/foo/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/bar/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Spring context is configured by XML file MY-REST-API-servlet.xml placed in a classpath. Nothing unusual as you can see.

There is a code which is not in ApplicationContext. I'm looking for a way to give this code an ability to reach some beans in my Spring MVC app. AFAIK `ContextSingletonBeanFactoryLocator` can be used to solve such problems. But small investigation I've done with dubugger shows that Spring MVC doesn't use it by default while loading a context. None of `getInstance()` methods in `ContextSingletonBeanFactoryLocator` was called as Spring MVC bootstrapping. Hence a context received through `ContextSingletonBeanFactoryLocator` will be not the same as one loaded during bootstrap. I think the problem will be resolved if I make Spring MVC to use `ContextSingletonBeanFactoryLocator` in a context loading process.

Is there a way to configure Spring MVC to use `ContextSingletonBeanFactoryLocator` during bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

change your web.xml file add `context-param` and specify the xml file  as describe below

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:MY-REST-API-servlet.xml
</param-value>
</context-param>

 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>MY-REST-API</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>classpath:MY-REST-API-servlet.xml  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```